# .htaccess removing .php extension, session variables not passed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am using a .htaccess file to remove the file extension (.php) from webpages. THe code I'm using from this site is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# turn off index.php for home page
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

So far so good, however, some web pages have $Session variables and the .htaccess files is stopping these variables from being passed. The pages that require seesion variable will not display at all, they are totally blank even when supplying correct login detail. I've checked the syntax for correct positioning of session_start() which appears at the head of the appropriate pages as follows:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
?>
```

All worked well until I added the .htaccess file.

Having read some Apache documentation I realise that I need to include [QSA] option. I've tried to include this in the above, however, all I get is 500 errors.

Could someone point out where I need to include QSA in the above?

Regards,

Bob

Hi all,

Thanks for your input. Keep it simple as I often say. The solution was so obvious I had overlooked it. I added the following after **RewriteBase /**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checklogin\.php$
```

Essentially excluding the include file from passing it's parameters. Et Voila!

I hope that this helps someone else with a session issue.

All the best,

Bob

Comment: A blank page often means that a fatal error appeared. Enable error_reporting: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);` and tell us what errors you receive. And check your apache error_log for the `500`.

Comment: Here's the log from the script loaded after the form has been submitted:Notice: Undefined index: myusername in /www/sites/020/c16/www.lbfl.co.uk/web/checklogin.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: mypassword in /www/sites/020/c16/www.lbfl.co.uk/web/checklogin.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: bollocks in /www/sites/020/c16/www.lbfl.co.uk/web/checklogin.php on line 19 So it's not passing the variables from the form?? The page is at www.lbfl.co.uk/client-pages.php

Comment: A undefined index won't throw a 500. What else is there in your log-file? Please edit your question. It is horrible to read the logs in a comment.

Comment: You don't need `QSA flag` and try commenting out first `RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]` rule.

Comment: Just for clarification: Session IDs are typically stored in a cookie and NOT in a GET variable (depending on your php.ini). So Apache redirects should be of no consequence to sessions.

Comment: @bobfelstead Please add your solution as an answer, then accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your input. Keep it simple as I often say. The solution was so obvious I had overlooked it. I added the following after RewriteBase /

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/checklogin\.php$
```

Essentially excluding the include file from passing it's parameters. Et Voila!

I hope that this helps someone else with a session issue.

All the best,

Bob